# Android google map custom marker getting error for java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a map application. I am using the new bottom navigation to load the first frame which deals with map. Below is my first function for onCreateView.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_activity_fragment1, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textRefresh);

        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior ;
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSheet));
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

        return view;
    }
```

Next I have the following which does the onMapReady. I purposely start calling my timer in this function so to ensure that its only called when the map is loaded.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        customHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}
```

Again in the updateTimerThread function I check if the map is not null.

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            // 10000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
            // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)



            MyCount counter = new MyCount(15000, 1000);
            markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            if (mMap != null) {

                Getdata gd = new Getdata();
                gd.execute("TEST");
                counter.start();
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 15000); // repeat body after  15 seconds
            }
        }
    };
```

This timer function calls private class Getdata extends AsyncTask { which call a json for new update and set new markers on the map. The issue now in the postexecute function. I have this line mCustomMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null); where I do call a custom marker and set things dynamically into the text view. I have even on destroy call super.onDestroy();
  and    mMap.clear();

I keep getting error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String s = result.trim();
            markers.clear();
            markersList.clear();
            mMap.clear();
            Log.e("onPostExecute ",result);            
            //markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();            
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mCustomMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

            Marker mk = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("-34"),Double.parseDouble("151")))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView))));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: `getActivity()` returns null.

Comment: I dont get you which getActivity? You mean ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null); ? What to check herE?

Comment: From the log - you are trying to perform `getSystemService()` on an object, that is null. Which means, getActivity() returns null.

Comment: So what should I put cause I am not too sure am I right or wrong?

Comment: I tried this too nflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null,false); but still getting error.